# What to do with a question on a technical problem that isn't actually a problem?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I ran into [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150454/xslt-counting-child-nodes) today that made me wonder what to do. The OP asks about a problem in his XSLT (trying to count some nodes) and says the result is incorrect. It turns out however that both his XSLT and result are correct, he just made a mistake counting himself to check the results. The reason it came up is that someone made some edits like turning "I am" to "I'm"

To me it feels like it should not be there, however it actually has some votes and an accepted answer (although there was nothing to solve in the first place).

Do you feel like it should/should not remain? And if not what would you do?

Answer (score 3):

Questions like this aren't useful for *future* visitors (well, apart from providing a *working* example of this particular XSLT technique). In general, we're happy that the author found their answer, but in the grand scheme of building a library of detailed answers to every question about [insert topic here], those kind of questions are practically useless.

Some sites, like Stack Overflow, have a special close reason for this:

> This question was caused by a problem that **can't be reproduced** or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, **this one was solved** in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Closed questions with a negative score eventually get deleted automatically by [Roomba](/help/roomba).

On other sites, it's (not yet) so much of a problem, but some Meta sites have a similar close reason for not reproducible problems.